# effective way to store and access an existing list of videogame characters with counters and synnergies with C++

Tags: database, list, class, vector, text-parsing

I'm attempting to make a DotA drafting companion application in C++

I'll give you a little run down of how it will work.  In DotA there are two teams of 5 players.  No character can be picked twice in a single match, meaning teams cannot share a character.  It is important to keep in mind both your team's and opponent's picks.  So what this will do is suggest characters for you to pick based on your and your opponent's teams.

To clarify, the existing list is not some sort of database, just a menagerie of suggestions on various websites, forums, and videos.  I would be organizing the list myself, and so my question is ultimately what format should I create this list in?

So for instance a popular character is Phatom Assassin who is strong with characters who can reduce armor, and weak against characters who can do lots of damage.

So a hero class might look like this

```
 class DotaHero
 {
     Name = "Phantom Assassin";
     vector<DotaHero> Counters{"Lina", "Lion"};
     vector<DotaHero> Friends{"Templar Assassin", "Shadow Demon"};
     CImg<unsigned char> src("PA.jpg");
 }
```

My program would allow you to input the first few heroes and then display a list of characters as a suggestion.

Should I...

1. Create a class for each and every hero in the game
2. Stream from a text file with each hero delineated by counters/friends
3. Create some sort of database to store each hero's counters/friends in

Please feel free to give any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

A very difficult question.

The question of what you store and how your express relationships between characters is going to define fundamentally how your tool works and how effective it is.

Of the top of my head I would create 2 weighted graphs,

1.) friends.
2.) counters.

Each node represents a hero and each edge of the graph would correspond to how strong of a counter or how strong of a friend you consider that hero. As heros are picks, find the highest weighted neighbor node to all of the current picked hero, and this would be your highest weighted suggestion. That would be the naive approach based only on the next pick (not always the best, a good way to get into trouble). Add layers and create weightings for 2nd order neighbors and you can start doing non deterministic analysis of the data set to get more sophisticated results.

Just a jumping off point. It would be a truly fascinating problem.

Comment: Great idea!  All heroes have multiple counters, some better than others so a weighted graph is perfect. But in this case I would still need to have an entry for each hero. At the moment I'm simply creating a hero class and having my main method place relevant information into each and every object using a loop. This seems a little verbose and I'm hoping there's a better way to get that info into the objects. Is there a serialization technique in c++ like there is in Java so that I can save these objects?

Comment: I would recommend using a graph data lib like http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html, and then the serilization technique can be anything you are comfortable working with, you just have to do the work of getting it ti deserialize.

Comment: If it were me I would use a triple store - The accepted standards answer would be some sort of XML file and XML parsing code which you can use either in a object style or triple store/RDF style. You can really use what ever you want as long as you figure out how to parse it.